# How can I register a function to be ran at exit?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to register a function "logout" to be ran if the python interpreter exists for some reason or another?

Comment: do you mean exits? If so what do you want to happen?

Comment: Have you looked at `atexit` in the stdlib?

Comment: but that is C/C++.... is there an equivalent for python 3?

Comment: To clarify, the function would be run just before the python interpreter exits.
I guess I could wrap the body of the main function in a try: finally: block to run the function in the finally

Comment: As they said: https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

Comment: OK atexit does it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, atexit from python's stdlib does it